# File isn't closing and read access violation exception in C?

Tags: c, file

I'm making kind of an antivirus as a part of a project I got. I need to find if a binary file includes a certain string anywhere in it. What I'm trying to do is add 7 chars to an array, because i know the virus signature is 7 chars long, then compare to the string and if they are equal, means the file is infected. But, it doesn't work. it says "Exception thrown: read access violation.
currStr was 0x1110113.". Also, whenever I try to free arrays or free files, the program crashed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 250

void Search_in_File(char* dir, char* str) 
{
    FILE *fp;
    DIR *folder;
    char currFilePath[ARR_SIZE] = { 0 };
    struct dirent *entry;
    int files = 0;
    char ch = 0;
    char* virusStr;
    char* currStr;
    char* buffer;
    int fSize = 0;
    int index = 0;

    folder = opendir(dir); //Opening the folder

    if (folder == NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to read directory");
        return(1);
    }

    virusStr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * ARR_SIZE);
    strcpy(virusStr, str); // Getting the virus detection string

    while ((entry = readdir(folder))) // Reading each file in the folder
    {
        if ((entry->d_name)[0] != '.') //Making sure that we will go over valid files only
        {
            strcpy(currFilePath, dir); //Coppy the folder name into the file path
            files++;
            printf("File %3d: %s\n",
                files,
                entry->d_name
            );
            strcat(currFilePath, "/"); //Add slash so we can add the filename and get full path
            strcat(currFilePath, entry->d_name); // Adding file name after the slash
            fp = fopen(currFilePath, "rb"); //Opening the file with the full path
            if (fp == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error opening file!\n");
            }

            fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
            fSize = ftell(fp);
            fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
            buffer = (char*)malloc(fSize + 1);
            fread(buffer, sizeof(char), fSize, fp); // Reading the file content into a string
            currStr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(str) + 1); //Memory for the checking string
            printf("%d", strlen(currStr));
            printf("%p", &currStr);

            for (index; index < fSize; index++)
            {
                printf("%c", buffer[index]);

                if (buffer[index] != EOF)
                {
                    //Error happens here
                    strcat(currStr[index], buffer[index]); // Adding the current char to the current string
                    // Checking if we have a string the same length as the virus signature
                    if ((index % strlen(virusStr)) == 0)
                    {
                        if (strcmp(currStr, virusStr) == 0) // Checking if we have the same string
                        {
                            printf("%s - Infected!", entry->d_name);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                currStr = '\0'; // Reset the current string
            }
            index = 0;
            currFilePath[0] = '\0'; // Resetting the file path in order to get the new one
        }
    }

    closedir(folder);
    //fclose(fp); //Doesnt Work - ????
    //free(virusStr); //Doesnt Work - ????
    //free(currStr);//Doesnt Work - ????
    //free(buffer);//Doesnt Work - ????
}
```

Comment: `currStr = '\0';` leaks your allocated buffer. Did you mean to have a `*` there?

Comment: Your compiler should should have caught that error. You are enabling warnings, right? (I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` when using `gcc`.)